# PHP log time 2 hours out from system time in localhost

Tags: php, pear

Im using ( and is new to ) PEAR.
When inserting, the time stamp is two hours earlier than my system time (running in localhost)

When writing to `LogEvent` table on my DB, I do the following

```
$le = new LogEvent;
$le->userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
$le->event = $msg;
$le->priority = (int)$priority;
if ($le->priority > 0) {
    $le->insert();
}
```

inside the `LogEvent` class the `insert()` looks like this

```
function insert() {
    $this->timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $le = parent::insert();
    return $le;         
}
```

The DB is on a VM Linux server on time      ( SYSTEM +2 : e.g.  06:00)
MY Windows LOCALHOST is running on well system time ( SYSTEM +0 : e.g.  04:00)
This insert writes the time in system min 2 ( SYSTEM -2 : e.g.  02:00)

why does this `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` give me the wrong time. If its running as or in localhost, should it not take my local system time?

Or am I overlooking something really obvious?

Comment: You need to adjust your server and database timezone. 
Right now your server might be configured to be +2 from your time, so when you get current time it gets current time + 2 hours.

Comment: Okay, hang on. Ill add more info regarding that.

Comment: Whats about PHP Timezone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP Timezone - runtime

```
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

PHP Timezone - php.ini

```
  date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```